# href appending current URL before navigating to new link

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, href

```
function setRedirect()
{
    var redirectDest = "This is additional description <a href=&quot;http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/&quot;>Click Me</a>.";
    if(redirectDest != null && redirectDest != '')
    {
        document.getElementById("RedirectDestElem").innerHTML = redirectDest;
    }
}
```

redirectDest is populated from Spring controller. So the function is actually

```
function setRedirect()
{
    var redirectDest = "${redirectDest}";
    if(redirectDest != null && redirectDest != '')
    {
        document.getElementById("RedirectDestElem").innerHTML = redirectDest;
    }

}
```

This appends current url base address to http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in and then redirects. I dont want this to happen. I have to convert `"` to `&quot;` in Java code (escape it) so that my java script does not break. Otherwise it will be

```
var redirectDest = "This is additional description <a href="http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/">Click Me</a>.";
```

which will break.

Comment: Why can't you use `'` instead of `"`? like this: `"This is additional description <a href='http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/'>Click Me</a>."`

Comment: Which URL being appended and in which order?   If the base URL being the first and the to-redirect-to URL being second, then there's a chance that it doesn't see the *http://* and think you are trying to redirect to a sub-page on the same domain. Try to escape with "\" instead of writing HTML entities. Or even better use a combination of  " "  and ' ' inside e.g. var=" this is the var values 'inside quotes' which will not break ".

Comment: @MoshFeu I cannot ask user to do that. Can I? As I said it comes from server where user sets it up on portal. He can choose to use `"` or `'`. Need to handle all cases in code.

Comment: So in the server or the client convert `"` to `'`. Is that a problem?

Comment: Inspect element and see the actual **href** value being generated inside the anchor.

Comment: So lets say its not href and string goes something like `Hi "there" ?` then "there" will get converted to 'there' which is not desirable. As you can see we just append innerhtml. href is just a particular case.

Comment: @Joraid Inspect element shows `<text id="RedirectDestElem" style="color:#0092EA;">
This is additional description <a href=""http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/"">Click Me</a>
</text>` on bowser. But I am sure it will be same as what is coming from server i.e with `&quot;`

Comment: Your issue is with the Quotation Marks single vs double. Why don't you use single quotations within the double? I couldn't understand what is the issue with what you said ** then "there" will get converted to 'there' which is not desirable**

Comment: If for some reason you are unable to use single quotations, then use the double quotation and escape them. **ESCAPE** means to add **backslashes** \   before the  "

Comment: var redirectDest = "This is additional description <a href=\"http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/\">Click Me</a>.";

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you enclose redirectDest in single quotes?

var redirectDest = '${redirectDest}';

Comment: The javascript variable "redirectDest" is getting its value from spring property "redirectDest" and not directly from the user. So, why not convert any single quote in the user entered string to be double quote before assigning to the  spring property "redirectDest".

Answer (score -1):

you can use the escape sequence "\"

so your text will be like below:

```
var redirectDest = "This is additional description <a href=\"http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/\">Click Me</a>.";
```